# ZF2 headLink helper ordering

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I have a small number of styles set with `$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet()` on the layout and I am trying to append another stylesheet from inside a view. However, the stylesheet from the view is always the first one rendered in the headLink stack.

layout.phtml:

```
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->basePath('css/styleA.css'))
                      ->appendStylesheet($this->basePath('css/styleB.css'));
```

Then in the view I've tried the following

view.phtml:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->basePath('css/sub/styleC.css'));
```

and

```
$this->headLink()->offsetSetStylesheet(100, $this->basePath('css/sub/styleC.css'));
```

However, both end up with styleC being the first link tag that is rendered. I understand that child views are rendered first (ie, view.phtml is rendered before layout.phtml), but I thought helpers like headLink and headScript have a shared stack as long as the renderer is the same. Is this assumption wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepend your stylesheets in layout, e.g.:

```
echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/styleB.css'))
                      ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath('css/styleA.css'));
```

and append stylesheets in view as you do it before.

Comment: Yes, but why? If the view helper stack is shared across views then doing offsetSetStyelsheet(100, ...) should move the stylesheet to the end, no?

Comment: It moves it to the end, but at that time the stylesheet container have only 1 item, and `then` the layout adds the others stylesheets.